# How to change theme of a total ASP.NET application dynamically?

Tags: asp.net, themes, skin

Imagine an ASP.NET application with several theme defined within it. How can I change theme of total application (not just a single page) dynamically. I know it is possible through `<pages Theme="Themename" />` in `web.config`. But I want to be able to change it dynamically. How shpuld I do it?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this on `Page_PreInit` [as explained here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx35bd89.aspx):

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (Request.QueryString["theme"])
    {
        case "Blue":
            Page.Theme = "BlueTheme";
            break;
        case "Pink":
            Page.Theme = "PinkTheme";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @this. __curious_geek, why do prefer to do it in Page_Load not Pre_Int?

Answer (score 3):

It is a very late answer, but I think you will like this..

You can change the Theme of the page in PreInit event, but you don't have use a base page..

In masterpage create a dropdown named ddlTema, after that write this code block in your Global.asax.. See how magic works :)

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    protected void Application_PostMapRequestHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page activePage = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
        if (activePage == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        activePage.PreInit
            += (s, ea) =>
            {

                string selectedTheme = HttpContext.Current.Session["SelectedTheme"] as string;
                if (Request.Form["ctl00$ddlTema"] != null)
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["SelectedTheme"]
                        = activePage.Theme = Request.Form["ctl00$ddlTema"];
                }
                else if (selectedTheme != null)
                {
                    activePage.Theme = selectedTheme;
                }

            };
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

keep a common base page for all your asp.net pages and modify the theme property between any event after `PreInit` or before the `Page_Load` in the base page. This will force each page to apply that theme. As in this example make MyPage as base page for all your asp.net page.

```
public class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the Page class.
    /// </summary>
    public Page()
    {
        this.Init += new EventHandler(this.Page_Init);
    }


    private void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.Theme = "YourTheme"; // It can also come from AppSettings.
        }
        catch
        {
            //handle the situation gracefully.
        }
    }
}

//in your asp.net page code-behind

public partial class contact : MyPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't do this in Page_Load, but in `PreInit`.